# calculating a simple 'ATM' using Memoization on Python

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I have created a code which receives `(amount, bills, n)`. bills is a tuple of available cash bills, and n is the number of times you have to use the bill exactly in order to receive the amount.

for example:

> atm_rec ( 70 (5,10) 7 )=True

and:

> atm_rec ( 10 (2,3,5) 6 )=False

I have created the following code using recursion

```
def atm_rec(amount, bills, n):
if amount==0:
    if n==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
elif amount<0:
    return False
elif len(bills)==0 and amount!=0:
    return False
else:
    tmp = atm_rec(amount - bills[-1],bills,n-1)
    tmp2 = atm_rec(amount,bills[0:-1], n)
    return tmp or tmp2
```

now I want to make it more efficient by using memoization(dict keys are tuples of `amount` and `n`, and values are Boolean) but somehow the code is much laggier. any advice why?

```
def atm_mem(amount, bills, n,memo = None):
if amount==0:
    if n==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
elif amount<0:
    return False
elif len(bills)==0 and amount!=0:
    return False
if memo==None:
    memo={}
key = (amount, n)  
if memo is not None and key not in memo:
    tmp = atm_mem(amount - bills[-1], bills, n - 1, memo)
    tmp2 = atm_mem(amount, bills[0:-1], n, memo)
    memo[key] = tmp or tmp2
return memo[key]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that you don't use your `memo` cache. This:

```
if memo is not None:
    tmp = atm_mem(amount - bills[-1],bills,n-1,memo)
    tmp2 = atm_mem(amount,bills[0:-1], n, memo)
    memo[(amount,n)]=tmp or tmp2
```

is executed no matter what when `memo` is set.

You have to avoid your computation by checking if `memo` contains your key, like this:

```
key = (amount,n)  # compute tuple only once
if memo is not None and key not in memo:
    tmp = atm_mem(amount - bills[-1],bills,n-1,memo)
    tmp2 = atm_mem(amount,bills[0:-1], n, memo)
    memo[key]=tmp or tmp2
return memo[key]
```

so when `(amount,n)` has already been computed, you don't enter in the `if`, just issue the pre-computed result.